# how to get just matching rows between two tables when one table has more rows than other

Tags: sql

For PID 666, there are two rows in table 2 and one row in table 1. I would like to see just one in my output.

```
table 1:
PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 

table 2:
PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 
666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 

Output:
    PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
    666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500
```

I do not wish to use row number as this creates an issue with my rest of the data.

how can I get this ?

Comment: `select * from table1` seems to do what you want.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: in a single row getting two values? that wouldnt be possible i think, to get both tables your have joins etc, but why do you have exact same 2 lines

Comment: this is how we get the data. it could be in either of the table , the rows will be repeated . I just have to pick one row which is matching between two tables. thsi can be done by having row number on each table.. but having row number will not work for my entire data set.

Comment: Try this: select * from table1
 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
 group by table1.pid